# How can we make the searchBar remain active until user search something or press cancel button

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

hello I have a `UISearchBar` on `NavigationBar`. If I type something in the searchBar it shows the cancel button on right and placeholder moves to the left. So at this stage If I tap somewhere else it comes back to original stage where there is no cancel button. So I want it to remain active until user types something or press cancel button. I mean it shouldn't do anything if a user taps somewhere else. I am confused what should I do. I have tried different things like below but they are not working.

```
func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        self.searchController?.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
        self.searchController?.active = true
        }
```